# Helm install fails on OS X

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've been trying for a couple hours to install Helm, and I can't figure it out. I followed the instructions here : http://helm-engine.org/guide/installing/. The full output of which is at the bottom. I've come across a couple cases which seemed similar to my problem [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/14123) and [here](https://github.com/switchface/helm/issues/57), but the solutions didn't work. Is there any way to install Helm on OS X Yosemite?

Output:

```
helm-test~ cabal sandbox init
Writing a default package environment file to
/Users/marcusbuffett/Documents/programming/playground/helm-test/cabal.sandbox.config
Creating a new sandbox at
/Users/marcusbuffett/Documents/programming/playground/helm-test/.cabal-sandbox
helm-test~ brew install sdl2
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/sdl2-2.0.3.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/sdl2-2.0.3.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring sdl2-2.0.3.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.3: 75 files, 3.9M
helm-test~ brew install cairo --without-x
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/cairo-1.14.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cairo-1.14.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring cairo-1.14.0.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.0: 106 files, 6.4M
helm-test~ brew install pango --without-x
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/pango-1.36.8.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pango-1.36.8.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring pango-1.36.8.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.36.8: 132 files, 4.8M
helm-test~ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
helm-test~ cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
/Users/marcusbuffett/Documents/programming/playground/helm-test/.cabal-sandbox
Configuring hashtables-1.1.2.1...
Building hashtables-1.1.2.1...
Installed hashtables-1.1.2.1
Configuring gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.0.3...
Building gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.0.3...
Installed gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.0.3
helm-test~ cabal install helm
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at
/Users/marcusbuffett/Documents/programming/playground/helm-test/.cabal-sandbox
Configuring sdl2-1.3.0...
Configuring transformers-base-0.4.3...
Configuring utf8-string-0.3.8...
Building utf8-string-0.3.8...
Building transformers-base-0.4.3...
Building sdl2-1.3.0...
Installed transformers-base-0.4.3
Configuring elerea-2.8.0...
Building elerea-2.8.0...
Installed utf8-string-0.3.8
Configuring cairo-0.13.0.5...
Configuring glib-0.13.0.6...
Failed to install cairo-0.13.0.5
Build log ( /Users/marcusbuffett/Documents/programming/playground/helm-test/.cabal-sandbox/logs/cairo-0.13.0.5.log ):
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /var/folders/6n/q0w_nmps7n72j9fvfy1lc40h0000gn/T/cairo-0.13.0.5-29788/cairo-0.13.0.5/SetupWrapper.hs, /var/folders/6n/q0w_nmps7n72j9fvfy1lc40h0000gn/T/cairo-0.13.0.5-29788/cairo-0.13.0.5/dist/dist-sandbox-5fb32753/setup/SetupWrapper.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/6n/q0w_nmps7n72j9fvfy1lc40h0000gn/T/cairo-0.13.0.5-29788/cairo-0.13.0.5/dist/dist-sandbox-5fb32753/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/6n/q0w_nmps7n72j9fvfy1lc40h0000gn/T/cairo-0.13.0.5-29788/cairo-0.13.0.5/dist/dist-sandbox-5fb32753/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/6n/q0w_nmps7n72j9fvfy1lc40h0000gn/T/cairo-0.13.0.5-29788/cairo-0.13.0.5/dist/dist-sandbox-5fb32753/setup/setup ...
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring cairo-0.13.0.5...
setup: Package xcb-shm was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xcb-shm.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xcb-shm', required by 'cairo', not found
Building glib-0.13.0.6...
Installed elerea-2.8.0
Installed glib-0.13.0.6
Installed sdl2-1.3.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cairo-0.13.0.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
helm-0.6.0 depends on cairo-0.13.0.5 which failed to install.
pango-0.13.0.4 depends on cairo-0.13.0.5 which failed to install.
```

Comment: Same problem http://pastebin.com/qjAJufRC. Could you install Helm finally?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is here:

```
Configuring cairo-0.13.0.5...
setup: Package xcb-shm was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xcb-shm.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'xcb-shm', required by 'cairo', not found
```

If you have installed XQuartx, the required files (xcb-shm.pc, etc.) are in `/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig`.

I was able to build `cairo` and `pango` by first setting:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Update:

I got compilation errors trying to build `helm-0.6.0` against `pango-0.13.0.3`. Here's how I was finally able to get a successful build:

1. cabal get helm-0.6.0
2. cd helm-0.6.0
3. Edit `helm.cabal` and add `glib` to the first `build-depends` section
4. Make the following edits on the file `src/FTP/Helm.hs`:

   - line 222: change `paFamily = textTypeface` to `paFamily = stringToGlib textTypeface`
   - add the import: `import System.Glib.UTFString (stringToGlib)`
5. cabal configure
6. cabal install

Comment: Okay, so what do I do about it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that when I'm back on my computer. I'm curious though, isn't the --without-x flag passed so that XQuartz isn't needed?

Comment: XQuartz is needed for X11 client libraries and header files. Also, it provides package-config files for these libraries which the cairo and pango build scripts need.

Comment: So close, everything installs fine except Helm itself, here's the output : http://pastebin.com/KpQmbMc0

Comment: As @Balthamos noted, you need sdl2-1.2.0. It looks like I installed it using `brew`. There is also a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PvLtUTariA) showing how to compile it from scratch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65636/discussion-between-user5402-and-marcus-buffett).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what user5402 said, you will also need to manually install sdl2-1.2.0. The latest version (1.3.0) is not compatible with helm currently.